# Python BeautifulSoup store URL after search

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I've created a script that types a log in and password, presses the log in button, goes to the search page, types the search and get the results page. 
I need to store this results URL so I can use Beautiful soup to extract the information I need. However, I can't use the requests library as I don't know the URL until I do the search.
Below is an example of my problem, I click the submit button which is fine, delay 2 seconds for the page to load. Then I'm trying to store the result page as variable r and use soup to get the information I need.

However with the below code I get the error 'str' object has no attribute 'content' so I think it's my r variable. Thanks in advance.

```
submitbutton.click()
time.sleep(2)
r = browser.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml') 
data = soup.find("div" , {"class": "specification"})
```

Comment: just use `r` instead of `r.content`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Presuming <sup>(*1)</sup> `submitbutton.click()` and `r = browser.page_source` are selenium calls, the value of "r" is a pure string - the HTML source of the page, at the moment you called `.page_source`.
As such, it does not have the `.content` attribute (the same exception you got), and you don't need it - you already have the html in it, just pass it as-is to BS's constructor:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
```

---

<sup>*1 The presumption is based on the question tag, and the method/attribute names, be more explicit the next time.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. You're 100% correct in the assumptions and solution. Works perfectly now. Appreciate that.